# C# - I'm trying to create MS SQL Connection (Connection string is in an XML file)

Tags: c#

XML file have MS SQL connectiongstring and read that XML in C#.
but that is not work.
error message is "invalidOperationException was unhandled"
how to solve it?

1.XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<db>
<connectionstring>Data Source=BALALOJANAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True</connectionstring>
</db>
```

2.C# Code

2.1 Namespace

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

2.2 XML Read code(it is in public form)

```
string connectionstring = "";
XmlTextReader re = new XmlTextReader("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlNodeType ty;
while (re.Read())
{
     ty = re.NodeType;
     if (ty == XmlNodeType.Element)
     {
        if (re.Name == "connectionstring")
        {
           re.Read();
           connectionstring = re.Value;
        }
     }    
}
```

2.3 Insert coding(button clock event)

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
sc.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into a(id,name)values '" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "'", sc);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Sucess");
sc.Close();
```

3.Error message
[image: Error message]

Comment: Surely simply stepping through this with a debugger would tell you where the issue is?  We don't need all 3 parts of the code.  Either the connection string is wrong, the XML code doesn't read it correctly or the way you're creating the connection is wrong.  It won't be all 3.

Comment: By posting the error as a screenshot you have successfully prevented anyone else with the same error from finding this question.

Comment: The [first hit on google](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixingInstanceFailureWhenConnectingToSQLServer2005Express.aspx) says it's likely the first of the 3 - your connection string is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From [Fixing Instance Failure when connecting to SQL Server](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixingInstanceFailureWhenConnectingToSQLServer2005Express.aspx)

> I was getting Instance Failure when connecting to my SQL Server.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindConnString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

> Trial and error just taught me that the problem was "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;"
>
> It's the double \\.
>
> That's an escape sequence in C#. Everything worked when I switched the connection string to .\SQLEXPRESS.

Your data source is `Data Source=BALALOJANAN\\SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 0):

It's like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OleDbConnection conn;
    conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\Microsoft Access\Northwind.mdb");

    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MyExcelTable([Fname], [Lname],  [Address])VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

Make sure you are using the Connection String the right way.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/